# Extract substring using python re.match

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as

```
sg_ts_feature_name_01_some_xyz
```

In this, i want to extract two words that comes after the pattern - `sg_ts` with the underscore seperation between them

It must be,

```
feature_name
```

This regex,

```
st = 'sg_ts_my_feature_01'
a = re.match('sg_ts_([a-zA-Z_]*)_*', st)
print a.group()
```

returns,

```
sg_ts_my_feature_
```

whereas, i expect,

```
my_feature
```

Comment: Have a look at this [demo](http://ideone.com/HZA7wq).

Comment: stribizhev is too humble to put his best answer as just a comment and leave without traces....

Comment: No, I just was looking after my 2 children, I have no time to write a full answer. Glad you could solve your issue with others' help. Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are asking for the whole match, not just the capture group. From [the manual](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group):

> **group([group1, ...])**
>   Returns one or more subgroups of the match. If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per argument. Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (the whole match is returned). If a groupN argument is zero, the corresponding return value is the entire matching string; if it is in the inclusive range [1..99], it is the string matching the corresponding parenthesized group.

and you asked for `a.group()` which is equivalent to `a.group(0)` which is the whole match. Asking for `a.group(1)` will give you only the capture group in the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask for the group surrounded by the parentheses, 'a.group(1)', which returns

```
'my_feature_'
```

In addition, if your string is always in this form you could also use the end-of string character `$` and to make the inner match [lazy instead of greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (so it doesn't swallow the `_`).

```
a = re.match('sg_ts_([a-zA-Z_]*?)[_0-9]*$',st)
```